# ODB2 adapter for raspberry

Tags: bluetooth, cars

I am thinking about using RPi in a car, as certainly many of you.

However, I am afraid that my demands are too high:

- gps dongle connection to track the position (I have already found a reliable dongle for this, two other products I had to return)
- gsm modem dongle - to have the data on-line, to track the vehicle
- bluetooth connection with some OBD2 device. I was searching, trying some, I had to return already one usb-like that did not operate with linux. I found a page https://www.obdautodoctor.com/obd-adapters, where kiwi3 looks nice (although quite expensive)

Do you have any experiences with an ODB2 dongle connection to RPi via bluetooth? Would you recommend the above one? Is there a OBD2 library for RPi that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend AMB (Automotive Message Broker) to manage those demands. 
https://github.com/tripzero/automotive-message-broker
and a OBDLink MX.  The AMB connects to each of those devices as plugin.
It also can be configured to log to a local sqlite db.
I've tried the OBDLink LX but it sometimes doesn't connect on boot.

Comment: Certainly a useful answer. I am searching fo MX, not available in my country and looks a bit more expensive (200$). One web says MX is bluetooth, another says WiFi. Is is BT or both versions exist?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution which has OBD, 4G, WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS and is built on pi zero. 
It seems to fit to your requirements:
https://www.autopi.io

I'm not sure if it has a built in library, but I think there is a github project called pyOBD, which will work on raspberry. Not sure which one is the official one.

Comment: thanks, PyOBD didnt work for me much, but I should re-iterate with new experiences in python.